# Can't get Odata 7.1 working in web api (.net core 2.2)

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I'm having trouble implementing `OData` in my Web API project.

I'm using `.NET Core 2.2` and `OData` (Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v7.1.0).
(I also have AutoMapper installed, but I don't think this is relevant)

The problem is that the response is never enriched with the extra properties (like odata.context and odata.count). Also, adding `?count=true` doesn't do anything either.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

This is my `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    /* AutoMapper config */
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
    });

    IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    services.AddMvc(opt => opt.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddOData();

    var connection = @"snipped-connection-string";
    services.AddDbContext<AllOnBoardContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

            /* CORS for local development, not ideal, I know */
    services.AddCors(setup =>
    {
         setup.AddPolicy(AllowCorsPolicyName, builder =>
         {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
         });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
          app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      else
      {
          // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
          app.UseHsts();
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();

      app.UseCors(AllowCorsPolicyName);

      app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
      {
           routeBuilder.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().MaxTop(10);
                routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("api", "api", GetEdmModel());
      });
}

private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Tenant>("Tenants");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

And this is my `Controller´ class:

```
public class TenantController : ControllerBase
{
   private ITenantService tenantService;

   public TenantController(ITenantService tenantService, IMapper mapper) : base(mapper, tenantService)
   {
       this.tenantService = tenantService;
   }

   [HttpGet]
   [EnableQuery()]
   public ActionResult<IEnumerable<TDto>> Get()
   {
      return Service.GetAll().ToList();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, OData query parameters always start with a `$`. So in your case, it is `?$count=true`.

Next, make sure that every Controller inherits from `ODataController`:

```cs
[ODataRoutePrefix("Tenants")]
public class TenantController : ODataController
{
   private ITenantService tenantService;

   public TenantController(ITenantService tenantService, IMapper mapper) : base(mapper, tenantService)
   {
       this.tenantService = tenantService;
   }

   [HttpGet]
   [ODataRoute]
   [EnableQuery]
   public ActionResult<IEnumerable<TDto>> Get()
   {
      return Service.GetAll().ToList();
   }
}
```

Annotations will help you to control OData. The prefix string of the `ODataRoutePrefixAttribute` specifies the OData URL path template that this action handles (in your case `http://<host:port>/api/Tenants`) and with the `ODataRouteAttribute` it is possible to specify the OData URL path template that this action handles.